# How to upgrade R version on a linux machine

Tags: r

I  have a 3.4 R version on my machine and i want to install the 4 version , after downlowding the package and making it my R version still at 3.4 . what is the problem ?  ( i have a ubuntu 16.04 working on my machine )

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html), the installation requires to add

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/
```

in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`

It is mentioned that

> R 4.0 packages for Ubuntu on i386 and amd64 are available for most stable Desktop releases of Ubuntu until their official end of life date. However, only the latest Long Term Support (LTS) release is fully supported. As of April 27, 2020 the supported releases are Xenial Xerus (16.04; LTS), Bionic Beaver and Focal Fossa (20.04, amd64 only). Note, to install R 4.0 packages, a different sources.list entry is needed. See below for details.

Comment: it is possible to install  the 4 version on a 16.04 ubuntu ?

Comment: @HallaMarwen  after adding the source path in sources.list, you can install R

Comment: You can add the repository with `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"`, which automatically grabs the right version for your Ubuntu.

Comment: i had done all the steps but when taping sudo R still the 3.4 version appear, do i need to unistall R and installing it again ? .